# How to count the ID with the same prefix and store the total number in another column

Tags: pandas, classification, feature-extraction, tabular

I have a dataset in which I noticed that the ID comes with info for classification. Basically, the last 2 digits of ID stand for their sub-ID (01, 02, 03, etc) in the same family. Below is an example. I am trying to get another column (the 2nd column) to store the information of how many sub-IDs we have for the same family. e.g., 22302 belongs to family 223, which has 3 members: 22301, 22302, and 22303. So that I have a new feature for classification modeling. Not sure if there is a better idea to extract information. Anyway, can someone let me know how to extract the number in the same class (as shown the 2nd column)

ID  Same class

23401   1

22302   3

43201   1

144501  2

144502  2

22301   3

22303   3

Comment: Sorry didn't make it clear. The expected output should be exactly as the 2nd column "same class". Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `str` slice and `transform`

```
df['New']=df.groupby(df.ID.astype(str).str[:-2]).ID.transform('size')
df
Out[223]: 
       ID  Sameclass  New
0   23401          1    1
1   22302          3    3
2   43201          1    1
3  144501          2    2
4  144502          2    2
5   22301          3    3
6   22303          3    3
```

Comment: I see the "New" column is like an index for different families, but I actually want to have the number of each family, like what my 2nd column shows. Sorry didn't make it clear.

Comment: @AlexXu what you mean index ? check my new =2 should be all under the same group

Comment: Yes, I agree they are in the same group. But the expectation is to have the number of the id in the same group. e.g., 22302 is in the group of 223, which has 3 members. So the output for anyone in the group should be 3 as an output. Does that make sense?